# C# OpenTK - Textured Quad

Tags: c#, bitmap, textures, opentk

I've recently downloaded OpenTK. I've created a basic game class and a quad. I've tried rendering a texture in my quad but it doesn't work. Here's my code.  This is the loading of the texture. (The texture class contains just an ID and a Bitmap. The GetWidth() and the GetHeight() just returns the Bitmap.Width and Bitmap.Height).

```
        Texture Texture = new Texture ();
        Texture.Bitmap = new Bitmap (Path);
        Texture.ID = GL.GenTexture ();
        GL.BindTexture (TextureTarget.Texture2D, Texture.ID);
        BitmapData data = Texture.Bitmap.LockBits (new Rectangle (0, 0, Texture.GetWidth (), Texture.GetHeight ()), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        GL.TexImage2D (TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, Texture.GetWidth(), Texture.GetHeight(), 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.Bitmap, data.Scan0);
        Texture.Bitmap.UnlockBits (data);
        GL.TexParameter (TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)All.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter (TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)All.Linear);
        return Texture;
```

This is the rendering method.

```
        GL.Enable (EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.BindTexture (TextureTarget.Texture2D, ID);
        GL.Begin (PrimitiveType.Quads);
        GL.TexCoord2 (0, 1); GL.Vertex2 (0, 32);
        GL.TexCoord2 (1, 1); GL.Vertex2 (32, 32);
        GL.TexCoord2 (1, 0); GL.Vertex2 (32, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2 (0, 0); GL.Vertex2 (0, 0);
        GL.End ();
        GL.Disable (EnableCap.Texture2D);
```

It renders just the quad and nothing else. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
GL.TexImage2D (TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, Texture.GetWidth(), Texture.GetHeight(), 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.Bitmap, data.Scan0);
```

with:

```
GL.TexImage2D (TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, Texture.GetWidth(), Texture.GetHeight(), 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
```

This should solve it. In yours there are format issues where what you used is does not accurately represent how System.Drawing.Bitmap represents 32bpp Argb bitmaps.